# How to use Chi-Square when there are more data points than degrees of freedom?

Tags: chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, degrees-of-freedom

I would like to use the $\chi^2$ statistic to evaluate the quality of fit of different models to an experimental data set that has many more data points than the number of independent Shannon Data Channels.  My understanding is the number Shannon Data Channels is the number of degrees of freedom in the data, and should therefore be the denominator of the $\chi^2$ analysis.

For a little context, the data I am considering is binned data, where the bin size is the width of a pixel on a 2D area detector (similar to the sensor on a CCD camera); the data of interest is a radial average of the 2D detector, the 1-D data is essentially the number of counts versus the distance from the center of the detector.

I have seen people approach the use of $\chi^2$ for this type of data two different ways:

1. transform the experimental data, interpolating it to a coarse grid that has as many points as there are Shannon Data Channels, $\nu$, then normalize by $\nu$ and say that good fits have a reduced $\chi^2/\nu\approx1$,
2. simply use all $N$ of the points, then normalize by $N$ and say that good fits have a reduced $\chi^2/N\approx1$.

These obviously give different results but I am unsure how to motivate one over the other.  I hesitate to use 1. as I think the interpolation step hides or loses information, and presents many opportunities to skew the result depending on how the interpolation is done.  I hesitate to use 2. as the result may be artificially low resulting from dividing by $N$.

Are either of these the correct approach and why?  If not, what would be a better approach and why is it better?